# Is it possible to query JPA entities by ElementCollections where the ElementCollection contains all elements in a given set of elements?

Tags: jpa, jpql, jpa-2.1

How to use JPQL to query JPA entities by ElementCollections where the ElementCollection contains all elements in a given set of elements?

For example, if a Node entity defines an ElementCollection of 'attributes'

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="node_attributes", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="node_name"))
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@Column(name="value")
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

I would like to find all Node entities that have a set of given attributes.  I have tried the following hoping the 'MEMBER OF' supports collections.

```
"SELECT n FROM Node n WHERE :attributes MEMBER OF n.attributes"
```

This query always returns an empty list.  Is a simple JPQL query possible for this use case?

Answer (score 3):

From JPA 2.0 spec, chapter *4.4.4 Path Expressions*:

> An *identification variable* followed by the *navigation operator* (.) and
>   a state field or association field is a *path expression*. The type of
>   the path expression is the type computed as the result of navigation;
>   that is, the type of the state field or association field to which the
>   expression navigates.
>
> An identification variable qualified by the KEY, VALUE, or ENTRY
>   operator is a path expression. The KEY, VALUE, and ENTRY operators may
>   only be applied to identification variables that correspond to
>   **map-valued associations** or **map-valued element collections**.
>
> A path expression using the ENTRY operator is terminal. It cannot be
>   further composed and can only appear in the SELECT list of a query.

So much for the theory. As for the question I see three slightly different answers depending on whether you want to search by `Map.Key`, `Map.Value` or `Map.Entry`:

```java
String qlKeys = "SELECT DISTINCT n " +
                "FROM Node n JOIN n.attributes a " +
                "WHERE KEY(a) IN :keys";
List<Node> nodes = em.createQuery(qlKeys, Node.class)
                     .setParameter("keys", Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"))
                     .getResultList();
```

```java
String qlValues = "SELECT DISTINCT n " +
                  "FROM Node n JOIN n.attributes a " +
                  "WHERE VALUE(a) IN :values";
List<Node> nodes = em.createQuery(qlValues, Node.class)
                     .setParameter("values", Arrays.asList("baz", "qux"))
                     .getResultList();
```

Keeping in mind that ENTRY operator can only appear in the SELECT clause we may have to replace it with conjunction of KEY and VALUE operators, i.e.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT n 
FROM Node n JOIN n.attributes a
WHERE KEY(a) IN :keys AND VALUE(a) IN :values
```

In the above examples:

- *identification variable* is represented by `c`
- *path expression* is represented by `c.attributes`
- *association field* is represented by `a`